# How to install Orchard CMS remotely?

Tags: installation, orchardcms

is it possible to install Orchard CMS remotely eg. on a hosting the way it can be done with Umbraco CMS?

I was trying to set up a website using OrchardSource zip or OrchardWeb zip but neither works for me. Not sure I can install it remotely or I need to run & compile the project first on my local machine?

Since I'm using Mac computer and I have no VisualStudio (only Xamarain Studio) nor MSSQL Client I am unable to do it locally.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Installing-Orchard. The web platform installer is the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

Use the install on IIS instructions from the documentation:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Manually-installing-Orchard-zip-file

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that on Mac OS X which has no IIS? @wentz

Comment: You're not installing it on your Mac, you're installing it on the remote host. At least it looks like that's what you were asking for in your question. Also, most Windows hosters support WebPI, which makes it possible to install Orchard (and Umbraco, and pretty much any well-known ASP.NET application) directly on the hoster's server in a few clicks.

Comment: @user1611620 I was assuming you have Remote Desktop Connection access to your hosting servers. I would first follow Bertrand's suggestion, if that doesn't work hopefully you can use RDC.